# Reliability of storing encryption/decryption key in KeyChain Access?

Tags: ios, encryption, jailbreak, keychain

I have to store data in SQLite database with encrypted format. I got working encryption/decryption code from net.

Now my problems are:

1. Safe place to store encryption/decryption key
2. What about keychain access to store key? Is it totally secure on jail-broken devices?

*Update:* Finally I decided to use keychain to store my crypto key.
I searched on net but what I found was to store Usename/password/CSR.

Can anyone please help to store simple NSData (my crypto key) in keychain?

Answer (score 5):

Use the keychain.  You won't be able to do better (if you could, you would not be asking the question).  It won't be totally secure (nothing is; ask Sony, or RSA) but it will be about as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for smart answer. I did implement successful. Seems like its very secure.